# Authorize.net not redirect to success or failure page magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.2.5, authorize.net

I am using magento latest version 2.2.5 and configured the Authorize.net direct post method as payment method. I tried to placed an order it saves the order in admin with pending state but **didn't redirect to success or failure page** please any one can advice on this issue.

I am getting below response after place the order.
Thanks

```
{success: true, authorizenet_directpost: {,…}}
authorizenet_directpost: {,…}
fields: {x_version: "3.1", x_delim_data: "FALSE", x_relay_response: "TRUE", x_test_request: "TRUE",…}
controller_action_name: "directpost_payment"
is_secure: "1"
x_address: "8778 High Ridge Drive"
x_amount: 1329.31
x_city: "Brooklyn"
x_company: "Test Company"
x_country: "US"
x_currency_code: "USD"
x_cust_id: ""
x_customer_ip: "111.11.11.111"
x_customer_tax_id: ""
x_delim_data: "FALSE"
x_email: "test@yopmail.com"
x_email_customer: "0"
x_fax: ""
x_first_name: "Jag"
x_fp_hash: "d4594a75aab8b43f31136e3699409363"
x_fp_sequence: "51"
x_fp_timestamp: 1536640689
x_freight: "0.00"
x_invoice_num: "000000034"
x_last_name: "Ram"
x_login: "48nL9pR49pEb"
x_merchant_email: "xxx@xx.com"
x_method: "CC"
x_phone: "01234567890"
x_po_num: ""
x_relay_response: "TRUE"
x_relay_url: "https://domain.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response"
x_ship_to_address: "8778 High Ridge Drive"
x_ship_to_city: "Brooklyn"
x_ship_to_company: "Test Company"
x_ship_to_country: "US"
x_ship_to_first_name: "Jagdish"
x_ship_to_last_name: "Ram"
x_ship_to_state: "New York"
x_ship_to_zip: "11206"
x_state: "New York"
x_tax: "101.31"
x_test_request: "TRUE"
x_type: "AUTH_CAPTURE"
x_version: "3.1"
x_zip: "11206"
success: true
```

Below are the settings which I have setup in admin[image]

Comment: are you using the sandbox or the merchant account?

Comment: I am using merchant account

Comment: 'x_response_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_code' => '1',
    'x_response_reason_text' => '(TESTMODE) This transaction has been approved.',

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No still facing issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached Screenshot configure everything as it is and it will work. I have tried and working properly.

[image]

** Note: Set Authorize.net to live mode don't set it to test mode. **

[image]

Comment: for sandbox account it is working for me but when I switched to merchant live account it stop the working.

Comment: @jack Set as per my screenshot and it will work

Comment: @Jack it is working?

Comment: Yes it is working with my details but not sure why it is not working with merchant account details.

Comment: try to generate new transaction key, verify api login id and  merchent id. i am sure there are mistake in that only.

Comment: if my answer is right then you can make it correct.

Comment: I have corrected but answer is different client used the MD5 key grater than 10 char that is creating problem

Comment: So finally solved